Request for a review for my circuit with the TP4056

Hi everyone, I designed this circuit that recharges a lithium ion battery via the TP4056, and I inserted an ON/OFF safety switch and a tactile button, both the switch and the button are used to turn on/off the load
I added a P-channel mosfet to prevent the load from being turned on while the battery is charging
I added a led to indicate if the switch is ON and a led on the button when it is pressed
On the TP4056 leds I put a 680 ohm resistor because I read on the datasheet that it can deliver a maximum of 5mA
Instead, on the other leds I put a lower resistor to take advantage of the 20mA of the led
The battery has a voltage of 4.2V
On the DW01A I made a modification on the CS pin, I needed to remove the short circuit and overcurrent protection, and instead of putting the CS pin on the GND (as is usually done) I put it on the negative of the battery because I I read that the DW01A protection works thanks to the voltage drop that the dual mosfet generates on the GND, so in theory the protection should never trip
The load is a 0.35ohm heater.
Do you think it is correct or are there problems in this circuit?

Green is 525nm +/-   25 not what you showed

If you copied this or designed this then show your logic for CV mode.

If you need to cut off the load while charging, all you need is the slider switch in between the charger and the load, why needs two AO3401? If you don't want the short circuit and overcurrent protection, why do you add DW01 and FS8205.

@hcheung how? They are two different mosfets, one is N-channel and one is P-channel… how can I use a single mosfet to turn off the load when there is power on the USB port and also turn on the load if the switch and the button are set to ON? I am using the DW01A with the FS8205 because I need the cutoff functionality when the voltage is too low

@D.A.S. I copied the charging circuit entirely from the Internet, except for the modification on the CS pin, the switch and the 2 mosfets that interrupt the load

then show your logic for CV mode.  If you do not monitor current to battery independent of load, you are at a big risk of frying your batteries in CV mode. One way is to disable charging if you sense CV and a load current with hysteresis on enable.

Here is what I got from a very brief review:

CC pins (configuration channel pins) these are used for power handling. These resistors help mark whether the USBC is a DFP (Downstream Facing Port) or an UFP (Upstream facing port). I assume this is a UFP, so you would need pull down resistors. 5.1k for default 500mA.

More information here.
Looks like C2 is decoupling for U2. Good job there, just make sure it is placed physically close to U2's VCC pin.
For the CE pin, I usually would use a pull up resistor. This will help I case you need to disable the component later during testing. This would make it easy to depopulate and repopulate to enable if needed.
For the RPROG resistor, looks like it is strapped for 600mA charge rate. Make sure this is acceptable for your battery.
Doesn't impact how the circuit works electrically but try to avoid having 4-way junctions in your schematic. Not really a big deal, just something that has been beaten into me haha.
Again, nothing about the circuit itself for this part, but the schematic can be hard to follow at times with nets crossing and things being upside down such as the grounds. I would recommend organizing a bit better to help with people reviewing your work!
Right now, BAT-1 is separate from GND. I would assume these would be the same, could be wrong here. Just thought I would raise the question. In the layout, these would be two nets and not a common ground.
The AO341A is a PMOS FET. Looks like it is setup to be connected through the pull down unless the USBC is plugged in. Looks good, but when this is plugged in, will not power your load. If this is an issue, can add a diode to deliver 5V to the load and still disable the PMOS FET.

Hopefully this helps, will look some more later on.

Thank you so much for the amount of information, I was not aware of that USB-C configuration pin... I will implement that connection!
As for the schematic, yes you are right... it is very confusing, I should organize it better...
BAT-1 and GND are 2 separate lines because in theory there should be nothing directly attached to the battery except the DW01A and the FS8205A that are responsible for interrupting the connection with the battery in case it is too low
I noticed now that I put the 2 mosfets with the load on the Source, do you think I should put them with the load on the Drain?

Of course, @KarimPanacci! For the PMOS, that is a good catch. I think for sure it should be connected load on the drain side. However I am not too sure about the NMOS Q2. For NMOS, load is connected to source in high side switching but I would recommend putting this through LTSpice qnd seeing what you get. Specifically the FETs and using PWL voltage sources to simulate some of the other things you can’t simulate easily
